# Power BI DAX : multi-column and multi-row condition and group by 2 columns

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Folks, I am trying to create a calculated column/measures and experiencing issues.

My Data-set looks like this:

| City | Building Name | Test Date | Component | Test Result | Calculated Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | - | - | - | - |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/3/2014 | Component A | Pass | None |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/11/2014 | Component 1 | Fail | Fail1 |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/11/2014 | Component 2 | Pass | Fail1 |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/11/2014 | Component 3 | Pass | Fail1 |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/06/2014 | Component A | Fail | MultiFail |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/06/2014 | Component 1 | Fail | MultiFail |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/06/2014 | Component 2 | Pass | MultiFail |
| City1 | Build1 | 1/06/2014 | Component 3 | Fail | MultiFail |

I am looking at Component & Test Result columns, count list of Fails - grouped by Building Name and Date; then generate Calculated result depending on the number of components failed.

> If Single component Test Result = fail - then Calculated Result = Fail1
> If CountA(components Test Result = fail) <=2 then Calculated Result = Fail2
> If CountA(components Test Result = fail) > 2 then Calculated Result = MultiFail
> If Component1 AND ComponentA Test Result = Fail then Calculated Result = FailMail

So far, I tried various ways in solving this with a step ahead and 2 steps behind:

I created a calculated column to count # Fails to be used for Calculated Result and struggling to generate Calculated Result.

> Tests_Failed =
> CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[TestResult]),FILTER(Table,Table[date]=MAX(Table[date])
> && Table[TestResult]="Fail"))

Another way I tried approaching the problem

> Calculated Result =
> VAR Component = Table[Component]
> VAR Date1 = Table[Test date]
> VAR Build = Table[Building Name]
> RETURN
> CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Component]), ALL(Table), FILTER('Table',
> 'Table'[Test Result]="Fail" && 'Table'[date] = Date1 &&
> 'Table'[Building Name]=Build)))

Comment: I think this is a DAX question

Comment: Appreciate your comment @RicardoDiaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Measure =
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Component] ),
            FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Test Result] = "Fail" )
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Building Name], 'Table'[Test Date] )
    )
VAR _2 =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        ISBLANK ( _1 ) = TRUE (), "None",
        _1 = 1, "Fail1",
        "MultiFail"
    )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Works as intended, @smpa01